# Computing a long sum with Clojure futures

Tags: concurrency, clojure, future

Running this code:

```
(ns playfield.core)

(defn sum
  [start end]
  (reduce + (range start end)))

(def size 1e8)

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println (time (sum 0 size)))
  (println (time (let [left (future (sum 0 (/ size 2)))
                       right (future (sum (/ size 2) size))]
                   (+ @left @right)))))
```

Gives me this output:

```
"Elapsed time: 2742.185 msecs"
4999999950000000
"Elapsed time: 2605.541 msecs"
4.99999995E15
```

I was expecting the second one to take roughly half of the time, since I'm distributing the computation on two threads. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like you loose most of the time in the per-step overhead resulting out of the use of lazy-seqs.

Comment: second twice fast for me: `12626.003474 msecs` vs `6696.957308 msecs`

Comment: Btw what super-computers do you guys have to sum up all 0-1e8? It takes ages on my machine, I cancelled it already. It runs on a 2.3 GHz 4-core processor

Comment: I got `4563.518 msecs` vs `2543.745 msecs` (the future version takes about 55% of the time of the straight one). You do have multiple cores on the machine you are testing this, right? And you aware of the trickeries with benchmarking the JVM? Maybe try [criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) instead? @lgrapenthin, I have a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 (Retina Macbook Pro, Mid 2012).

Comment: Yes I have not benchmarked using criterium, I just tried it with time and it took for ever. It's possibly leiningens default JVM settings.

Comment: FYI, `(frequencies (map type (range 0 1e6))) ;=> {java.lang.Long 1000000}` but `(frequencies (map type (range 1e6 2e6))) ;=> {java.lang.Double 1000000}`

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm using a 2.4Ghz i5, looking at the Activity Monitor actually shows all 4 cores spinning, which is also weird. I'm not really looking for a precise benchmark, just wanted to be shure I was using futures correctly.

Comment: @Giuseppe What's your Clojure version and how are you running (REPL, lein run, lein trampoline run, jar,...)? If you copy and paste as above in the REPL and run `(-main)` a few times in a row, do you get consistent results as above?

Comment: BTW, my somewhat cryptic FYI above was to say that you are in part measuring the difference in time to sum a range of double versus a range of longs. It doesn't account for difference with expectations, which is, I would guess, a JVM warmup issue.

Comment: @A.Webb I was using `lein run`, in the REPL:
1st run: 2952 vs 2608
2nd run: 3216 vs 2760
3rd run: 3234 vs 2759

Answer (score 1):

I modified your example a bit (adding `(shutdown-agents)` at the end of `-main`) and ran (`lein run -m playfield.core`) it on two machines:

**Retina Macbook Pro, Mid 2012**

- 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7
- 16 GB RAM
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)

Results:

```
serial:   2678.034 msecs
parallel: 1943.153 msecs
Parallel takes 72.3% of baseline.
```

Note that these results differ from my original comment. That data was run from a REPL.

**Lenovo Thinkstation S20**

- 3.07GHz Intel Xeon W3550
- 8 GB RAM
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)

Results:

```
Serial:   12390.296313 msecs
Parallel:  6856.656525 msecs
Parallel takes 55.3% of baseline.
```

I can think of two problems you might have while benchmarking:

1. The machine doesn't have multiple cores / Java is restricted to one core / the cores are otherwise loaded.
2. Benchmarking the JVM is tricky. Generally, it's recommended to use [criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) instead. However, My numbers above were generated just using `time`, so I'm not sure that comes into play here.

**EDIT**

Some more ideas I had:

As @lgrapenthin mentioned, JVM options can affect the times. For example, lein uses the following two options to [improve startup time](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Faster#tiered-compilation): `-XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1`. Changing this has obvious differences for this case:

```
$ LEIN_JVM_OPTS="" lein run -m 'speed.core'
Serial:   2496.435288 msecs
Parallel: 2045.084565 msecs
Parallel takes 81.9% of baseline.
```

The comment from @Giuseppe states that 4 cores are being actively used (I assume this means fully utilized). Perhaps that JVM has high memory pressure, and the CPU usage is the garbage collector frantically working to make some memory available. I wasn't able to reproduce this locally, however.

Comment: @Giuseppe Is that graph showing the CPU usage across your entire system, or is it limited to the Java process? If the former, it's not very useful, and I would suggest looking at the CPU percentage listed by the `java` process specifically.

Comment: It show the CPU usage across the entire system, but it should be enough to show that the cores are not saturated and that all cores are used